# Refreshing a page in a browser yields POST or GET request?

Tags: post, browser, get

I am learning asp.net mvc form processing now and confused with the following:

What happens if we push the refresh button on the browser? 
It makes a POST or GET request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is dependant on the last call that was made by the browser to get the current data. Eg:

a) If you submitted a form, performing a POST and then hit refresh, the browser will do another POST.

b) If you just clicked a link that took you to another page, performing a GET, you'll a refresh will perform a get.

If you're just starting out understanding the GET/POST methods, there is a nice pattern that you should understand that will help you not get in situations where data is posted again and again by users who constantly refresh the browser after a POST:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

and

[An example specifically for asp.net MVC](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Using-Post2c-Redirect2c-Get-Pattern.aspx)

Comment: Thank for answering. I understand now. For completeness, what happens if we press back or forward buttons?

Comment: Your links are really informative and useful for me. THanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever HTTP method was used to generate the page will be repeated when you hit refresh.

If you're using `<% Html.BeginForm(...) %>` when the form is submitted, it will create a POST, and if the resulting page is refreshed, it will repeat the POST.

Comment: so it is recommended to redirect to another page in the action method processing the post form fields?

Comment: It's not necessary to redirect or render a different view. You can pass your results back in ViewData or ModelState.